# How to change line stroke color in vega-lite with condition

Tags: vega-lite

I have a graph in vega-lite and try to change color of points and lines depending on the upper limit (obeGrenze) of the green shaded area, e.g. set color to red, if point is above this upper limit.
Code:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A dual axis chart, created by setting y's scale resolution to `\"independent\"`",
  "width": 300, "height": 300,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://pnwscm60.github.io/data/chdeath.csv"
  }, 
  "axis": {
    "font": "Open Sans Condensed"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
        "field": "date",
        "axis": {"format": "%d.%m", "title": null},
        "type": "temporal",
        "timeUnit": "daymonth"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"opacity": 0.3, "type": "area", "color": "#85C5A6"},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Alter == \"65\""}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "field": "obeGrenze",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1800]},
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "Anzahl wöchentliche Todesfälle", "titleColor": "#111","format": ".2r"}
        },
        "y2": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "field": "untGrenze"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"opacity": 0.3, "type": "area", "color": "#85C5A6"},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Alter == \"0-64\""}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "field": "obeGrenze",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1800]},
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y2": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "field": "untGrenze"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "stroke":"#85A9C5", "type": "line", "interpolate": "monotone","point": true},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Alter == \"0-64\""}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "hochrechnung",
          "type": "quantitative",

          "axis": {}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "stroke": "#85A9C5", "type": "line", "interpolate": "monotone","point": ""},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Alter == \"65\""}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "hochrechnung",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Alter == \"65\""}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "hochrechnung",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [{"field": "Woche", "type":"quantitative"},{"field": "hochrechnung", "type":"quantitative"}],
        "fill": { "value": "#fff" }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "point",
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.Alter == \"0-64\""}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "aggregate": "mean",
          "field": "hochrechnung",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [{"field": "Woche", "type":"quantitative"},{"field": "hochrechnung", "type":"quantitative"}],
        "fill": { "value": "#fff" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can change the color with condition e.g. "test": "datum['hochrechnung'] > 100", but when I try to  use a variable instead of a number (e.g. "datum['obeGrenze']", I don't have any effect.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/project.html see selections in encoding section

Comment: @AKS page not found

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes https://vega.github.io/ and what you can find in it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there is a way to give credit for the original fix; but this works

[solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185612/can-i-bind-a-condition-to-a-slider-when-the-condition-uses-a-datum/76188246#76188246)