# can I bind a condition to a slider when the condition uses a datum?

Tags: vega-lite

This is a chart that I have; I would like to tie the percentage text conditional test to the slider, is there a way to do this?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "avg_score": "4.2000000000000000",
        "call_count": 15,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "avg_score": "2.3333333333333333",
        "call_count": 15,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "percent",
      "value": 80,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 100}
    },
    {"name": "gt", "expr": ""}
  ],
  "description": "",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "label",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "call_count", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "avg_score", "title": "avg score", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "axis": null,
          "field": "percentage",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "title": "Scores"
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"}
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum['percentage'] < 80", "value": "red"},
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {"field": "percentage", "format": ".2%"}
      },
      "mark": {"align": "left", "type": "text", "x": 5}
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "max_score", "type": "quantitative"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "the maximum for the score",
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Scores",
  "width": 200
}
```

[my chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqULKQI4aFWpRLiSQQzgQ0AbVBJiZAPrQ2AJz3oALJQBMABn8BgUGKIFCmgg5QbAyymGgAjGJKgkhMcIL6AHJ8mDSkAAQA6q7KlkrIAB5OUW4Jvko4cC5QcLFIZO4gvpQefkH9-SAAvgq29tWund6UAMxz8wuLMyFhghFRMXGoicmp6foAgrIQAO5N+QAqNLohlRO1qEkgjc2t6h363R4AbL9--wDvgFhgBdEbPJAuHSWVA2EDaG7oF4tWIhExmdwADnqICYNFkyjQoHxOAYWxAUNkH3K+IS5SQFTqviGIy0Ok6ZDiSjgFRwLn0oKUygsUBcNBwuTkAu5siiynxZCJIAAnkqGTQYaAUmlBDDMC5zEpclAANYAISQBP0KMwTRCxpNAHkcEgoHRVagcblMIJOsMlAAzGjpQnobX7I3Kxr6WRsBD40zDcHwGhkLBKiC2nAJb7glLKu2w0CtOUKpWYNhsQS5bNFkBBkPW8KRaKoo10X1NtZlECYKOdACODEt3rUeT0rPrwcEoZAdkczlq7Z9nXn+UXekj0fQQ5HdDHpEFIEZmjnZDIbgotv0EAYCBC6phsgYa0D09nyLe7U3IGgpncoDKHGSC0rC9TxGCy6dugADKNQWEm9IuCaSpRIIrj6AAxMoOH2pW1bimg+qGr2-b6EwkKIcWspsPKVKoVWGGnlEBJ0Ow8inramb6KomB3lYADkn5tB0AkgvkAA8+TYmipjmPobiEuC6LyegF5wK0-q9jyWygA2M76MJ7w-gGrjIOSPgAKSISAyDIWqwhkBxIC+gGXKkdu2kVO5J5iCyowgCWtFlpxOlKvps53Bu9pkTuw6xPuuSHv5tmQihp6mKmzmue5FEQOk+KdPGOGdkKJ7eB4gZyJghRwKm6boEwVaEka+E1vo9BwPklTXHe+SmS4+Sdeu8ExZ5treUmIJQZ0cGTD2Jw0Mo9BoH0QxAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "avg_score": "4.2000000000000000",
        "call_count": 15,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "avg_score": "2.3333333333333333",
        "call_count": 15,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "percent",
      "value": 80,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 1, "max": 100}
    },
    {"name": "gt", "expr": ""}
  ],
  "description": "",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "label",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "call_count", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "avg_score", "title": "avg score", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "axis": null,
          "field": "percentage",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "title": "Scores"
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"}
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {"test": "datum['percentage'] < (percent/100)", "value": "red"},
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {"field": "percentage", "format": ".2%"}
      },
      "mark": {"align": "left", "type": "text", "x": 5}
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "max_score", "type": "quantitative"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "the maximum for the score",
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Scores",
  "width": 200
}
```